# Change jLable-text from another class

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

My problem: I can't change the text of a jLabel from an other class. In my JFrame-Class, which is called "NewJFrame" I have defined a method called "setLabelText()" in which the text of jLable1 is changed. This method is called from the main-Method, but the text doesn't change. What's wrong? would be very grateful for help!

```
public class Main {

    static NewJFrame f = new NewJFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        f.main(null);
        f.setLabelText("changedText");

    }

}
```

and here my new JFrame class with a lot of generated stuff in there. The important thing is the setText()-Method.

```
 public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(156, 156, 156)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(203, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(152, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(132, 132, 132))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        



    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


    public void setLabelText (String text){
        jLabel1.setText(text);

    }



    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Do you need to set text to the label or not? if it is label what is this: `static NewJFrame f = new NewJFrame(); f.setText("changedText");`?

Comment: you're right that's unclear. I have edited my question and changed the methods name in "setLabeltext()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to call the setText()-method from Main-class

What is the purpose of `f.main(null);` and you are trying to set text to the `JFrame` in this line: `f.setText("changedText");`

As a solution, change your `JLabel` access modifier to `public`. By default it is `private`, because of that you cannot change it in another class.

Change:

```
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
```

To:

```
public javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
```

**In netbenas you cannot edit generated codes by default**. So to change access modifier, **right click on the `JLabel` in design window*** and go to the **customize code**. In that window change the **Access:** to **public**.

[image]

Now, change the `Main` class as below:

```
public class Main {
    static NewJFrame f = new NewJFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f.jLabel1.setText("changedText");//this line will get the label in NewJFrame and set the text
        //f.setVisible(true);//this is added to open the frame. May be you dont want this line
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you've made me aware of a more general mistake: it isn't even necessary to make the jLable1 public, but it just suffices to leave out `f.main(null)`. Apparently, when f.main is executed first, no changes can be done to the jLable anymore, which I do not really understand.

Comment: @taxus1 fine. If you do not want to change the access modifier you can implement a method and pass the value. Is your program working now?

Comment: I have finally figured out my mistake now: In main-Class I used `f.main()`in order to make the frame visible and initialize it and so on. But having a closer look, the method main() contains `public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }`, so that everytime I call it, it creates a new instance of NewJFrame, which is set visible instead of my frame "f", whose text has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

When you create JFrame frame (from netbeans) it already have its main function in it. so either you have to create JPanel and manually initialize in your class having main function, or you can move f.setText("XYZ"); to the NewJFrame() class. 
It would be like :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ***NewJFrame f=new NewJFrame();
f.setVisible(true);
f.setText("Your Text Goes Here");***
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I need to call the setText()-method from Main-class, because in there the setText-String will be generated. I still haven't understood the reason, why the text is not changed: Isn't it the same, whether I apply setText() within the class or call the public setText()-method from another class?